# How do I rename column in w3schools sql?

Tags: sql, alter

I am trying to rename a column name in [w3schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_between)

```
ALTER TABLE customers
  RENAME COLUMN contactname to new_name;
```

However, the above code throws syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I am just trying to show my friend how the `alter rename` works

Comment: It can vary by database.

Comment: There is no such thing as "w3schools sql".

Comment: Check out [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) which lets you choose from several different database flavors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this to rename the column in SQL Server:-

```
sp_RENAME 'TableName.[OldColumnName]' , '[NewColumnName]', 'COLUMN'
```

> sp_rename automatically renames the associated index whenever a
>   PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint is renamed. If a renamed index is
>   tied to a PRIMARY KEY constraint, the PRIMARY KEY constraint is also
>   automatically renamed by sp_rename. sp_rename can be used to rename
>   primary and secondary XML indexes.

For MYSQL try this:-

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE [COLUMN] old_col_name new_col_name
```

Answer (score 2):

From "Learning PHP, MySQL & JavaScript" by Robin Nixon pg 185. I tried it and it worked.

`ALTER TABLE tableName CHANGE oldColumnName newColumnName TYPE(#);`

note that `TYPE(#)` is, for example, VARCHAR(20) or some other data type and must be included even if the data type is not being changed.

Comment: Reading the manual really seems to be a skill that is no longer en vogue

Answer (score 0):

@Hannah's answer definitely helped me there but, as it took me some time to translate the syntax into real-life, I thought it might help someone to get an actual real-life example on how to use this syntax on MySQL.

1.So here again is the syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName CHANGE oldColumnName newColumnName TYPE(#);
```

*NB: TYPE(#) is, for example, VARCHAR(255) or some other data type and must be included even if the data type is not being changed.*

2.Here is my real-life example, where "dashboard_dummy" is my table name, "product_code" my old column name and "order_id" my new column name:

```
ALTER TABLE dashboard_dummy CHANGE COLUMN product_code order_id int;
```

Hope it helps!